# Call UIAlert on Darwin notification center callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios9

I created a Darwin Notification on my ViewDidLoad and I want to call an UIAlert when the callback is called. In this case, I want to call an alert when the screen is unlocked, to do that I'm going to create a variable that will be set TRUE/YES when this callback is called for the second time  (considering that the first time will be when the user locks the screen and the second time when the user unlocks the screen). When this variable is TRUE/YES, the alert will be called.

How can I do that?

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad]; 
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), 
                                NULL, 
                                hasBlankedScreen, 
                                CFSTR("com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen"), 
                                NULL, 
                                CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
}

static void hasBlankedScreen(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
{
    /*
    if(isUnlocked){
        [self myAlert];
    } else{
        isUnlocked = true;
    } 
    */
}

- (void) myAlert{
    UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"HEY"
                                  message:@"Screen is unlocked"
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                              [self pop];
                                                          }];

    [alert addAction:defaultAction];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's easy:

1) Pass `(const void*)self` as observer into `CFNotificationCenterAddObserver` instead of `NULL`;

2) Use a `(__bridge ViewController*)observer` in `hasBlankedScreen` instead of `self`.

Complete code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
                                    (const void*)self,
                                    hasBlankedScreen,
                                    CFSTR("com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen"),
                                    NULL,
                                    CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
}

static void hasBlankedScreen(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo) {
     if (self.locked) {
         [(__bridge ViewController*)observer myAlert];
         self.locked = NO;
     } else {
         self.locked = YES;
     }
}
```